# Why isn't index.html loading when I enter my site's domain name?

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, httpd

This is my first time using an Amazon EC2 Linux Micro Instance with Ubuntu 12.04.

I noticed it did not have Apache installed by default, so I did `sudo apt-get install apache2`. After installation, `/var/www/index.html` exists and I verified that Apache2 is running.

When I did `curl http://localhost:80`, it successfully returned the content in `/var/www/index.html`.

However, when I type the public DNS name into a browser I get a `page not found` error.

Why isn't `index.html` loading and what might the solution to this be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like you forgot to add an allowance for TCP port 80 requests inbound in the security group for that server.

[Here's some info](https://cartwrightlab.wikispaces.com/Amazon+EC2+Security+groups) on EC2 security group config